# Exact sequence of vector spaces and sum of dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, summation, exact-sequence

> Let
> $0\xrightarrow{}E_0\xrightarrow{u_0}E_1\xrightarrow{u_1}E_2\xrightarrow{}\ldots\xrightarrow{}E_{n-1}\xrightarrow{u_{n-1}}E_n\xrightarrow{u_n}0$
> be an exact sequence. Then $$\sum_{2k+1\leq
>  n}\text{dim}(E_{2k+1})=\sum_{2k\leq n}\text{dim}(E_{2k}).$$

Write $F_k:=\text{Im}(u_k)$. Then $\text{dim}(E_{k+1})=\text{dim}(F_k)+\text{dim}(F_{k+1})$ for all $0\leq k\leq n-2$. I would like to show that both sides of the above equality are identical with $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\text{dim}(F_k)$.

The indexing of the sums is proving to be a challenge. How can I rewrite $\sum_{2k+1\leq
 n}\text{dim}(E_{2k+1})$ in terms of the $F_k$? Ideally I would like to reindex the first sum and then use that to show that the identity holds.

Comment: The computation is easier if you prove that $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}{(-1)^k\dim{E_k}}=0$.

Comment: ^that is exactly the way to go

Comment: @Mindlack. Would that sum make sense even if the $E_k$ are not all finite dimensional?

Comment: No, unfortunately. But sums with infinite cardinals are easier to handle.